# Does using a templating engine increase performance of a web applications?

Tags: performance, cakephp, template-engine

I have been developing several web applications using cakephp 2.x framework and mysql database, but a friend told me that they are using twig templating engine in there projects and its working fine, i have been using just pure cakephp no templating engines, if i am to adopt a templating engine;

1. Which is the best compatible with cakePhp 2.x?
2. Will there be any effect on the performance of the application?
3. What are the pros and cons of using a templating engine in cakePhp
      2.x?

Answer (score 1):

1) A quick Google search for "cakephp twig" would have revealed this: https://github.com/predominant/TwigView I guess there are plugins for Smarty as well around. You can google that yourself I think. The best integrated one with Cake is probably CML https://github.com/jameswatts/cake-markup-language

2 & 3: IMO the only reason to use a template engine is when you have to have people write views that use php functions but you don't trust them so that you have to parse the template in another template language to avoid direct use of php. A template engine will always add overhead, it is logical that it will.

php was built as template engine so why use yet another one on top of php? The argument "designers have to learn php" is invalid: They'll have to learn the template "language" as well. I don't see a difference in having them to learn php `foreach($users as $user)` vs `{% for user in users %}` (that's Twig).